# Burial at Sea tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we add tags for [bioshock-infinite](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioshock-infinite) Burial at Sea DLC?  If so, how should we go about it, since it was released in 2 parts?  My guess would be to make it 1 tag called [burial-at-sea](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burial-at-sea) or something, since [the-walking-dead](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead) did not split up individual episodes.

Comment: The first thing to ask is: Is there significant advantage to having separate tags for the DLC vs. the main game? I don't know the answer, because I'm not familiar with this game, but we really prefer to err on the side of fewer tags.

Comment: @StrixVaria Based on [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126540/clash-in-the-clouds-can-money-be-used-for-anything) it seems the DLC may have some changes from the base game.  It is also nice to keep potential spoilers away from users that may not have the DLC yet.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest [bi-burial-at-sea](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bi-burial-at-sea) which fits parameters established by things like [tf2-heavy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-heavy) etc.

Comment: clash-in-the-clouds did not use that format

Comment: @Batophobia it should have done.